# Visualizing GFP in transgenic rice seeds?

Tags: botany, biotechnology

I want to express GFP in rice as a method for differentiating transgenic from non transgenic rice seeds. I want to know if I can visualize them using a hand held UV lamp as the GFP I will be using has a excitation maxima at 395nm. If yes, how is to be done? Do I just flash the UV lamp on the seeds in the dark room and I can see the GFP expressing seeds glowing green?

Comment: I don't know about GFP in rice, but I've made GFP expressing bacteria, and they glowed ok on a UV tansluminator usually used for DNA gels. The RFP colonies I made were visibly red even without UV, but glowed good too. A simple UV transluminator would probably be fine, and you should have one for working with DNA anyway.

Comment: 395 nm is not quite UV, so if you're not getting a strong enough signal (depending on the exact wavelength your transluminator emits, and the excitation profile of your protein), you could try using a purple light bulb. You can sometimes find them in big-box home centers like Home Depot, Lowes, etc., and you should also be able to find them at party stores. BTW, are you using GFPuv?

Comment: I am using mgfp5, optimized for plant expression which has excitation maxima at 395nm and 473-477nm(blue).What should I do?